# Column "? column?" indicated repeatedly

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-view

I want to create a view but such an error occurs:

> column "? column?" indicated repeatedly

```
CREATE VIEW v_users AS
    SELECT 
        users.user_id,
        users.full_name,
        users.username,
        users.password,
        roles.role_name,
        roles.role_id,
        users.roles_id,
        'users.createdAt',
        'users.updatedAt',
        'roles.createdAt',
        'roles.updatedAt'
    FROM users
    INNER JOIN roles
    ON users.roles_id = roles.role_id;
```

Comment: Can it just be that you need to give names to the strings you are selecting? When you quote something postgres wil just return the string, not the column. Since it's just a hardcoded value postgres doesn't have a name to give it.

'roles.createdAt' as createdAt or something might work.

Comment: Why are you selecting hard-coded string values in the view?

Answer (score 1):

Column `createdAt` and `updatedAt` may come from different table but having the same name in view, so you must give `Alias` for that.

Try Below

```
CREATE VIEW v_users AS
    SELECT 
        users.user_id,
        users.full_name,
        users.username,
        users.password,
        roles.role_name,
        roles.role_id,
        users.roles_id,
        'users.createdAt' AS UserCreatedAt,
        'users.updatedAt' AS UserUpdatedAt,
        'roles.createdAt' AS RoleCreatedAt,
        'roles.updatedAt' AS RoleUpdatedAt
    FROM users
    INNER JOIN roles
    ON users.roles_id = roles.role_id;
```

Comment: Hah, not the cause of the error in the question, but they were certainly going to run into this problem next :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not selecting columns, you are selecting string constants in your view. And the string constants don't have names, so Postgres names them "`?column?`".

I strongly assume you don't actually want to have the string value `'users.createdAt'` in your view, but the actual *content* of the respective table column. You need to remove the single quotes for that.

As you have multiple columns (`createdat`, `updatedat`) with the same name, you need to give them a proper alias:

```
CREATE VIEW v_users AS
SELECT 
    users.user_id,
    users.full_name,
    users.username,
    users.password,
    roles.role_name,
    roles.role_id,
    users.roles_id,
    users.createdAt as user_created_at,
    users.updatedAt as user_updated_at,
    roles.createdAt as roles_created_at,
    roles.updatedAt as roles_updated_at
FROM users
  INNER JOIN roles
   ON users.roles_id = roles.role_id;
```